# SQL Server Cursor Dynamic SQL Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_KLIENT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, database-cursor

```
declare kursor cursor for 
    select 
        exec_No, insert_type, stg_table, src 
    from 
        METADATA.dbo.METADATA 
    order by 
        exec_No asc;

    declare @insert_type varchar(15), @stg_table varchar(30), 
            @src varchar(80), @SQL varchar(254), @exec_No numeric(2), 
            @SQL_INSERT varchar(254);

    open kursor

    fetch next from kursor into @exec_No, @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        if @insert_type = 'select' 
        begin
            --  select @SQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID('''+@stg_table+''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE '+@stg_table;
            select @SQL = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+@stg_table;
            select @SQL_INSERT = 'select * from '''+@src+''' as '+@stg_table;
            exec(@SQL);
            execute(@SQL_INSERT);

            fetch next from kursor into @exec_No, @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
        end 

        if @insert_type = 'bulk'
        begin
            execute ('truncate table ' + @stg_table);
            execute('BULK INSERT '+@stg_table+' 
                     FROM ''' + @src + ''' 
                     WITH
                         (
                            FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
                         )')
        end

        fetch next from kursor into @exec_No, @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
    end

    close kursor;
    deallocate kursor;
```

and I get errors

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_KLIENT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_MIEJSCOWOSC'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_PRACOWNIK'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_MELDUNEK'.

Errors are generated by statement :

```
select @SQL_INSERT = 'select * from '''+@src+''' as '+@stg_table;
```

my inserts for metadata :

```
insert into 
METADATA.dbo.METADATA(exec_No,src,stg_table,temp_table, chd_table, insert_type) 
values(1,'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_KLIENT', 'STAGE.dbo.STG_KLIENT', 'TEMP.dbo.TEMP_KLIENT', 'CHD.dbo.KLIENT', 'select');

insert into 
METADATA.dbo.METADATA(exec_No,src,stg_table,temp_table, chd_table, insert_type) 
values(15,'SOURCE.dbo.SRC_MELDUNEK', 'STAGE.dbo.STG_MELDUNEK', 'TEMP.dbo.TEMP_MELDUNEK', 'CHD.dbo.MELDUNEK', 'select');
```

Any ideas how to get it working?

Thanks guys !

Comment: `PRINT` (or `SELECT`) the value of your dynamic SQL statement's variable. If you can't figure out the problem there, then paste the output(s) of those `PRINT` statements. `'select * from '''+@src+''' as '+@stg_table;` isn't right though (object names aren't quoted in single quotes (`'`)). `QUOTENAME` is your friend, but you have a problem with your data (explained below).

Comment: Ahh,you're storing a full object name in your table. That's a problem; don't. Split out the parts into the database, schema, and object namein your data; then you can quote each part separately. Otherwise you leave yourself open to injection; that's a **big** problem.

Comment: Also, on a side note. Formatting your code is a really useful thing. You have no indentation in that query, making it very difficult to follow. You have multiple `IF`, `WHILE` statements, and it's impossible to tell what `END` belongs to which `BEGIN`. Get into the habit of using indentation and line breaks when writing SQL. Left ragged code is note a good way to write SQL.

Comment: It won't run, but here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ca76e186c2419c2d89328a9b9c1f9a6) with some formatted code and some comments.

Comment: Thank You. Is it possible to make my code working? It's for small project - I don't have much time to change the METADATA table structure. I'll keep in mind that it's better to split data to smaller parts. Could you try to correct my code?

Comment: I could, but I won't provide a solution that is open to injection; so it would need to change your design.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally done this. 
There's a working(I do right now know it's not safe) code:

```
declare 
    kursor cursor for select exec_No, insert_type, stg_table, src from METADATA.dbo.METADATA order by exec_No ASC;
    declare @insert_type varchar(15), @stg_table varchar(30), @src varchar(80), @SQL varchar(254), @exec_No numeric(2), @SQL_INSERT varchar(254);
    open kursor
    fetch next from kursor
    into @exec_No, @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            if @insert_type = 'select' 
            begin
                select @SQL = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+@stg_table;
                select @SQL_INSERT = 'select * into ' + @stg_table + ' from ' + @src;
                print(@SQL);
                print(@SQL_INSERT);
                exec(@SQL);
                exec(@SQL_INSERT);
            end 
            if @insert_type = 'bulks'
            begin
            execute ('truncate table ' + @stg_table);
            execute('BULK INSERT '+@stg_table+' 
                        FROM ''' + @src + ''' 
                        WITH
                        (
                        FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
                        )')
            end
            fetch next from kursor
            into @exec_No, @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
        end

    CLOSE kursor;
    deallocate kursor;
```

In SQL Server `select * from table_1 as table_2` isn't correct query. Correct one is `select * into table_2 from table_1`.

Also there were duplicated '`fetch next ...`' blocks(one inside first if, another one outside ifs).

Thanks for help guys !